# MongoDB installation error on window 7

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

mongodb taking forever to install. Can someone please help..i have window 7, 64bit and nodejs already installed.I have installed uninstalled and tried installing again but the installation cant go completion..

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB installer mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.2-signed.msi has a checkbox that's auto selected to download and install Compass.  Uncheck this and the installation should complete.  You can then download and install Compass separately.

[image: Uncheck option to download and install Compass]